# Rails: generate a key and make it readonly

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I got an `Order` model.

It should have a random generated `key` field (and I need to save it to database).

Once it is created, the key should be readonly.

How can I do it?

**PS:**
I created @key instance variable in `after_initialize`, but it does not want to be stored in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instance variables are not stored in the database, only the properties generated from database columns.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your `key` field is attr_reader and that you have a migration that adds the key field to your model's database table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks and [ActiveRecord::Dirty](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty) to do what your want.

Create a column in your database such as key which will be a String.

Then in your model add this.

```
before_save :set_key_if_needed

def set_key_if_needed
  if self.persisted?
    self.errors.add(:key, 'key cannot be changed') if self.key.changed?
  else
    self.key = "Your key randomly generated"
  end
end
```

If persisted?(if the object has been saved to database already) you check if the key has changed, and if so you prevent the validation to succeed.
Otherwise you just generate your key.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `before_create` callback to generate the key. then overwrite the `key=` accessor to prevent overwriting of this key:

```
def key= value
  raise "not allowed, you fool!"
end
```